# Probability: understanding Event Independence

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I'm trying to understand independence and have questions.  I present my understanding and follow with questions.

Independence is defined on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) as "two events are independent if the occurrence of one does not affect the probability of occurrence of the other" in which the following equality applies:
$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$

In the following example, I classify independent and dependent events. Do the following classifications of events look correct?

I use $\Omega = \{a, b\}, F = \mathcal{P}(\Omega), P(\{a\})=P(\{b\}) = \frac {1} {|\Omega|},  P(\Omega) = 1,  P(\emptyset) = 0$:

Independent Events:
$$
P(\Omega \cap \Omega) = P(\Omega)P(\Omega),
P(\emptyset \cap \emptyset) = P(\emptyset)P(\emptyset), 
P(\Omega \cap \{a\}) = P(\Omega)P(\{a\})
$$

Dependent:
$$
P(\{a\} \cap \{a\}) \ne P(\{a\})P(\{a\}),
P(\{a\} \cap \{b\}) \ne P(\{a\})P(\{b\})
$$
the first dependent event, occurance of $\{a\}$ effects the probability of the the second $\{a\}$ such that it's probability is $1$.  For the second dependent event, the same applies with a probability of $0$.

Finally, for an outcome represented as a sequence of two trials:
$$
\Omega = \epsilon \times \epsilon, \epsilon = \{a_1, ..., a_d\}      
$$
$$
A = \{a_1\} \times \epsilon, B = \epsilon \times \{a_2\}, A \cap B = \{a_1\} \times \{a_2\}
$$
$$
P(A) = \frac {|A|} {|\Omega|}, P(B) = \frac {|B|} {|\Omega|}, P(A \cap B) =  \frac {|A \cap B|} {|\Omega|}, P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)
$$
the events $A,B$ are independent. Two dependent events are $A \cap B, B$, because occurrence of one effects probability of the other.

Comment: Your second example is much better, because you have “enough” events to get useful examples of independence. Your first example has a confusion: there is no “second $\{a\}.$” Either $a$ happened or it didn’t. An event $E$ is independent of itself only if $P(E)=0$ or $P(E)=1.$

Comment: Since $\Omega = \{a\}, \{b\}$, then $|\Omega| = 2$ and $P(\{a\}) = P(\{b\}) = 1/2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, for the "second $\{a\}$" comment, I attempted to fit the example into the mentioned grammatical description of independence classification.  Do you know how this example fits that classification?